# Locally free group scheme étale

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, group-schemes

Let $R$ be a commutative ring, $p >0$ prime and $G$ a finite, locally free group scheme over $R$ of rank $p^n$; $n \in \mathbb{N}_{\ge 1}$. Assume $p \in R^*$ (i.e. is a unit in $R$).

Question: Why this condition on the rank implies that $G$ is étale?

By definition etale is equivalent to flat & unramified. As $G$ is locally free it's obviously flat. Be unramified is also a local condition. Thus we can translate the problem to commutative algebra and asking why the free $R$-module $R^{p^n}$ is unramified at a prime $\mathfrak{q} \subset R$ if $p \in R^*$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not so easy, but relies on a well-known structure theorem for connected group schemes over a perfect field.

**Lemma 1.** *A finitely presented morphism $Y \to X$ of schemes is unramified if and only if $Y_x \to x$ is unramified for all $x \in X$.*

*Proof.* See [EGA IV$_4$, Cor. 17.4.2]. $\square$

Thus, we may reduce to the case $R = k$ for $k$ a field, and by flat descent to the case where $k$ is algebraically closed. Then unramified for a finite extension means (geometrically) reduced.

**Lemma 2.** *A finite group scheme over an algebraically closed field is a semidirect product of an étale group scheme and a connected group scheme.*

*Proof.* See for example [Wat, §6.8]. The étale part is $\pi_0(G)$ and the connected part is $G^0$. $\square$

**Theorem.** *If $G$ is a geometrically connected finite group scheme over a perfect field $k$ of characteristic $p > 0$, then $\Gamma(G,\mathcal O_G)$ is isomorphic to $k[X_1,\ldots,X_n]/(X_1^{p^{e_1}},\ldots,X_n^{p^{e_n}})$ for some $e_1,\ldots, e_n \in \mathbf Z_{>0}$.*

*Proof.* See for example [Wat, §14.4]. I don't know a quick summary of why this is supposed to be true (I would be interested if someone does), but the proof is not that hard. $\square$

**Theorem.** *If $G$ is group scheme over a field of characteristic $0$, then $G$ is geometrically reduced.*

*Proof.* See for example [Wat, §11.4]. $\square$

In particular, if the rank of $G$ not divisible by $p$ (e.g. $p = 0$), then $G^0$ has to be trivial and $G$ is étale. $\square$

---

**References.**

[EGA IV$_4$] A. Grothendieck, [*Éléments de géométrie algébrique. IV: Étude locale des schémas et des morphismes de schémas (Quatrième partie).*](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=PMIHES_1967__32__5_0). Publ. Math., Inst. Hautes Étud. Sci. **32**, p. 1-361 (1967). [ZBL0153.22301](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0153.22301).

[Wat] W.C. Waterhouse, [*Introduction to affine group schemes*](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4612-6217-6). Graduate Texts in Mathematics **66** (1979). [ZBL0442.14017](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0442.14017).

Comment: Your final note I not fully understand. By your reduction steps we apply two base changes: first one we take a prime $\mathfrak{q}_x \subset R$ and do base change along $R \to R_{\mathfrak{q}_x} \to R_{\mathfrak{q}_x}/\mathfrak{q}_x=k(x)$ (can now apply Lemma 1) and then change base to alg closure via $k(x) \to \overline{k(x)}$ by the flat descent argument as you said). Set $k=k(x)$ and we are now in the setting of the Theorem, i.e. set $G=G^0$ (only con c), $\Gamma(G,\mathcal O_G)= k[X_1,\ldots,X_n]/(X_1^{q^{e_1}},\ldots,X_n^{q^{e_n}})$ where $q$ is the characteristic of $k$. Obviously $q$ is

Comment: prime to $p$ as $p \in R^*$ by assumption. 

If $q>0$: rank of $k[X_1,\ldots,X_n]/(X_1^{q^{e_1}},\ldots,X_n^{q^{e_n}})$ is a power of $q$ but also of $p$, a contradiction. That's fine. But what about the case $q=0$. Then the theorem isn't applicable...

Comment: @TimGrosskreutz: right, I forgot to mention the characteristic 0 situation. There everything is reduced, so a finite group scheme is always étale.

Comment: one remark: could you give a reference for the statement that in case where $k$ is algebraically closed, then for a finite $k$-module (thus a field) unramified is equivalent to  (geometrically) reduced?

Comment: See for example Tags [00U3](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00U3) and [030W](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/030W) (but the latter deals with separable transcendental extensions as well).

Comment: It is obvious that a finite locally free morphism is unramified if it is at every point (no need to appeal to EGA).

Answer (score 2):

Since unramified-ness is local, and since $G$ is a group scheme, it is sufficient to show that, for a finite flat commutative group scheme $G$ of order $n$ over an algebraically closed field $k$ whose characteristic is prime to $n$, the structure morphism is unramified at $0$.

This is equivalent to that the tangent space of $G/k$ at $0$ is $0$.

And this is easy: [$n$], the "multiple by $n$" map on $G$ induces the one on the tangent space.
Since $n$ is invertible on $k$, it is an isomorphism.
But by Deligne, [$n$] is $0$ on $G$.
Thus the tangent space is $0$.

Comment: The OP does not assume that $G$ is commutative. This is needed for Deligne's result; the same statement without that assumption is an open problem (at least over a general base).